# Save an object in multiple other objects using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I currently try to make a simple Catalog web view and I am using Spring and Hibernate to save the data. I want to have a `Template` which is a `Product` and in this Template there should be multiple `Ingredients` which are also `Products`.

These are my classes:

**Template.java**

```
@Entity
public class Template extends Product implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

    public Template(String name, Money price, ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients) {
        super(name, price);
        this.ingredients.addAll(ingredients)
    }

    // Getters and setters...

}
```

**Ingredient.java**

```
@Entity
public class Ingredient extends Product implements Serializable {
    public Ingredient(String name, Money price) {
        super(name, price);
    }
}
```

**Product.java**

This class comes from the salespoint framework. It handles saving of the *name* and *price* but it also handles things like the **ID** for Hibernate.

**public void initialize()**

This method provides dummy data for testing purposes.

```
public void initialize() {
    Ingredient cheese = new Ingredient("Cheese", Money.of(1, "EUR");
    Ingredient bacon = new Ingredient("Bacon", Money.of(1, "EUR");
    Ingredient tomato = new Ingredient("Tomato", Money.of(1, "EUR");

    // add these ingredients into ArrayLists (3 Lists)
    // list1: tomato, bacon
    // list2: bacon, tomato, cheese
    // list3: cheese, tomato

    Template pizza1 = new Template("Pizza 1", Money.of(1, "EUR"), list1);
    Template pizza2 = new Template("Pizza 2", Money.of(1, "EUR"), list2);
    Template salad = new Template("Salad", Money.of(1, "EUR"), list3);

    // saving these in a catalog
}
```

When running this code I always get an error of this sort:

```
Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_TAGDVK3J2NBLU2MQMBL8HBJV9_INDEX_1 ON PUBLIC.PRODUCT_INGREDIENTS(INGREDIENTS_PRODUCT_ID) VALUES ('f6f05610-ca1f-40b6-b0a8-abaccbc0452b', 2)"; SQL statement:
insert into product_ingredients (template_product_id, ingredients_product_id) values (?, ?) [23505-197]
```

I interpret this error like this: Hibernate tries to create a table to link templates with ingredients but the ingredients keys appear more than once.

When I tried adding only one ingredient per list (so one lsit with only cheese, one with bacon, ...) it works perfectly fine.

I don't quite know how to search for this topic and I tried googling it but I did not find anything yet. What changes do I have to make to make this code work, so that one Ingredient Object can appear in multiple Templates?

Comment: Looks more like a `@ManyToMany` relation instead of `@OneToMany`

Comment: please include complete entity code

Comment: @Selaron Well I guess I completely forgot that. That is actually the answer. Could youu please write it as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined a `@OneToMany` relation between `Products` and `Ingredients` which is in fact a `@ManyToMany`.